# Why do I get different layouts for boxes in LyX?

Tags: lyx

In LyX (Version 2.2.0), whenever I have a box, if it's a minipage or a parbox, the "Standard" layout disappears, and instead I get a "Plain Layout" option (which looks like it uses monospaced fonts?), while if I use "None" for the inner box, the layout combobox gets disabled, so I can't even choose a layout.

What is the reason for this? What is the usage of "Plain Layout", and why is it only available inside parbox/minipage? Why can't I use "Standard" in a parbox/minipage?

Comment: A `minipage` is a bit different from standard text, in the default classes. For example, paragraph indentation is set to zero. But the font should be the same, so if you really get monospaced fonts inside a minipage, then I at least would need more information to understand why. I don't understand what *None* means in this context.

Comment: I've voted to close. If you provide a minimal example `.lyx` file that demonstrates this, I'll be sure to vote for reopening, just ping me in a comment.